# What's the difference between setting the Animated Value in the onPanResponderMove method via "Animated.Event" and "setValue"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated, react-animations

If you want to drag and drop an element with PanResponder, you could pass the values of the movement to the onPanResponderMove method in two ways:

### 1. With Animated.Event

```
onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
    null,
    { dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y }
]),
```

### 2. With .setValue

```
onPanResponderMove: (evt, gesture) => {
    this.state.pan.setValue({x: gesture.dx, y: gesture.dy})
},
```

Both appear to do the same thing in my tests. What is the difference?